# Expected expression error assigning value in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, function

I am a new Objective-C programmer and I am working on a project.

I created a function which returns a `float` value and I declared some variables into it as shown here :

```
-(float)WN8Calculation{
    int avgDAMAGE,avgFRAGS,avgSPOT,avgDEF,avgWIN;
    long battles;
    double expDAMAGE,expFRAGS,expSPOT,expDEF,expWIN;
    double rDAMAGE,rFRAG,rSPOT,rDEF,rWIN;
    float rDAMAGEc,rFRAGc,rSPOTc,rDEFc,rWINc;
    float wn8;
    int tank_id;

    avgDAMAGE =2;

    return wn8;
}
```

When I assign the value for the variable `avgDAMAGE` I get an error in that line  saying "expected expression". Can someone help?

Comment: You should really break that `avgDAMAGE = ...` line down into multiple statements. It will be a so much easier to find the problem. You're also missing a semi-colon off the return statement.

Comment: it's supposed to be in one line because i'm parsing a json object to get an int value, so i guess breaking it in multiple statements would be useless but i will try it.
thanks for your answer.

EDIT: i changed that line with `avgDAMAGE =2` and i keep on getting the error

Comment: No, it's not supposed to be in one line. Make it into six. It will be easier to read and debug.

Comment: Where's the semicolon after the `return wn8` line?

Comment: oh i'll add it, it was a missclick. thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @rmaddy even if i change all of that with `avgDAMAGE=2` i keep on getting the error.

Comment: Copy and paste the actual real code giving the error. Don't type the code into the question. Copy and paste it. And use the version with `avgDAMAGE=2`.

Comment: Comment the whole method. Look if there is still the error. If NO, comment line by line to find out where is your mistake. If YES, then the error may be before or after. Where did you put it exactly?

Comment: I copy and pasted your updated code from your question into my own project and I get no such error. Are you putting this code in a .m file? It is inside a class implementation?

Comment: @rmaddy yes i'm putting this code in a .m file and waht do you mean inside a class implementation ?

Comment: Your are writing an instance method therefore this method in your question must be between the `@implementation SomeClass` and `@end` lines of the .m file.

Comment: @rmaddy oh yes it is indeed between the `@implementation SomeClass` and `@end`.

Answer (score 0):

Well i solved this error (i guess) what i had to do is to just delete the line a rewrite it..
Thanks for your help guys.